# Discord Autocode reaction reply bot (not reaction role bot)

Tags: discord, bots, autocode

I have been using autocode.com to create some Discord bots. I have very little programming experience and found autocode to be quite easy. However, I've tried asking a question on autocode's discord that no one seems to understand or is asking.

I am trying to create a bot that replies to reactions--but does not assign roles, but instead, provides a reply--either in thread or a DM to that user who uses that specific emoji reaction.

For example, this is what I am looking to do: if there is a bot message in #channelx, userX will react to that message with a pepperoni emoji and then a pizza bot will reply back with a message either in thread or DM  such as, "Hi @userx, your pizza topping has been recorded and will be ready for pickup in 15 minutes, please visit this link.com to track your order".

Autocode has a bot that can react to reactions and assign roles but I can't seem to reverse engineer it give a reply, rather than assign roles.

I appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What does autocode use? Python or node.js? If python, you can do something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('message'):
        await message.channel.send('hi')
```

If node.js, you can do something like this:

```
client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'specific message') {
        msg.reply(`response text`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was previously a Community Hero at the Autocode Discord server. Try finding another app through [this](https://autocode.com/app/), and if none are available, the thing to do would be looking through the [API's](https://autocode.com/discord/api/). Here's one [for messaging](https://autocode.com/discord/api/channels/0.3.2/messages-create/) in general, here's one for [responding](https://autocode.com/discord/api/interactions/1.0.1/responses-create/), and here's one for [dm-ing](https://autocode.com/discord/api/users/0.2.1/dms-create/).

Let's say, for example, I'd be making it reply to a reaction through DM:

- The first thing you do is make sure the event trigger is set to `message.reaction.add`. This is so that the code you will write is triggered whenever a reaction is added.
- Make either a switch or if statement to change what happens depending on what reaction triggers the code. In this example, I'll just use an if statement for easy explanation.

```js
const lib = require('lib')({token: process.env.STDLIB_SECRET_TOKEN});

if (context.params.event.emoji.id == '1234567890') {
  await lib.discord.users['@0.2.1'].dms.create({
    recipient_id: `${context.params.event.member.user.id}`,
    content: `Hi <@${context.params.event.member.user.id}>, your pizza topping has been recorded and will be ready for pickup in 15 minutes, please visit this link.com to track your order`
  });
}
```

What this does is check if the thing that triggered this event has the emoji id equaling `'1234567890'`: If it does, then it follows into that if statement, and if it does not, it skips over it.

In the future, please stay patient in the Autocode Discord server; The ones who are helping are also community members, similar to here. You may always ask the same question every now and then.